# Unity virtual joystcik and touch Input

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

when I am using a virtual joystick for player movement my touch input for turning player is not working. It's working only if I don't use joystick. I've tried different approaches with using events to handle both types of imput.

```
private void Update() {
// Get joystick input for movement
float horizontalJoystickInput = joystick.Horizontal;
float verticalJoystickInput = joystick.Vertical;

// Apply movement based on joystick input
Vector3 movement = new Vector3(horizontalJoystickInput, verticalJoystickInput, 0 f) * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
transform.Translate(movement);

// Check for touch input
CheckTouchInput();
```

}

```
Here is my touch control handling... May be I need to use some kind of thread handling?

private void CheckTouchInput() {
if (Input.touchCount > 0) {
    Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);

    switch (touch.phase) {
    case TouchPhase.Began:
        // Check if touch begins on a UI element
        if (EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject(touch.fingerId)) {
            isTouchTurning = true;
            touchStartPos = touch.position;
        }
        break;

    case TouchPhase.Moved:
        if (isTouchTurning) {
            float turnInput = (touch.position.x - touchStartPos.x) / Screen.width;
            transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward, turnInput * turnSpeed);
        }
        break;

    case TouchPhase.Ended:
    case TouchPhase.Canceled:
        isTouchTurning = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

}